# Query prepared using Prepared statement in db2 is failing

Tags: java, db2, prepared-statement

We have a db2 database v 9.7 FP 1

We have a table something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB1(COL1 VARCHAR(30),...);
```

Our application takes col1 value from front end and forms a PreparedStatement in Java 7, something like this: `SELECT FROM TAB1 WHERE COL1 = '?'`. If the input from UI is having > 30 characters, on execution of the prepared statement, we are getting an error with DB2

```
 Error Code: -302
```

But the same statement i.e., SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE COL1 = 'XXXXX'; (with COL1 length > 30 characters), if executed directly on the database from cmd, we are not encountering any errors.

What are the possible reasons for this error message?

Comment: A question without code attracts vague answers.

Comment: I assume `VARCAHR` means `VARCHAR`.

Comment: I'm amazed that "executing directly" does not cause an error.

Comment: 1. Yes, executing directly doesnot throw any errors.
2. Yes, it is VARCHAR

Answer (score 1):

Error code 302 is exactly related to exceeded capacity of the column:

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n302.dita

Comment: But it is a select statement, and not an insert/update statement, where the column length constraint comes into picture.

Comment: It looks like DB2 can't compare varchar(30) column with a parameter exceeding the limit

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats right. The column is limited to 30 characters, so when you select query resultset if > 30, it would throw an error.